# How to find Duplicates - by referencing to the first column?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I am very new to coding, so apologies for a very basic question. 
I am trying to find duplicates within a sheet by checking the value in the first column.

If the values match, then the row that is not the most recent is deleted.

```
function removeDuplicates() {
    var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("TEST")
    var data = sheet.getRange(1, 1, sheet.getLastRow()).getValues();
    var newData = [];

    for(var i=0;i<sheet.getLastRow();i++){
        for(j=0;j<newData.length;j++){
            if (newData[j][0] != data[i][0]){
                var fullrange= sheet.getRange(i,1,1,17); newData.push(fullrange);
            }
        }
    }
    sheet.clearContents(); sheet.getRange(1, 1, newData.length, newData[0].length).setValues(newData);
}

------------------------------------------------------------------------
```

The above code is matching the entire row against one another. I have tried multiple codes from StackOverflow - but all in vain.

I appreciate if anyone can please help me with this!

Comment: This code is nice, but it would be helpful if we could see the data structure. But I can tell you this will come down to using `Array.prototype.filter`.

Comment: can you share your spreadsheet I'll be happy to help live. Best.

Comment: What makes a row to be the most recent?

Comment: Hi Ruben - the row that has been edited most recently amongst the duplicates :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
function removeDuplicates() { 
  var ss=SpreadsheetApp.getActive();
  var sh=SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName("Sheet1") 
  var rg=sh.getDataRange();
  var dA=rg.getValues();
  var col=1;//comparison column
  var nA=[];//unique data 
  var cA=[];//unique array of dA[i][col-1] ie the comparson array

  for(var i=1;i<dA.length;i++){ 
    if(cA.indexOf(dA[i][col-1])<0){//if the first column of the current row is not in the cA array then that's a keeper so we put the first column of this row into the cA array and we put the whole row into the nA array.  If it is in the cA array then it's a duplicate so we don't push the first columns or the whole rows.
      cA.push(dA[i][col-1]);
      nA.push(dA[i]);
    }
  } 
  var sheet=ss.getSheetByName('Sheet18');//I used another sheet so I didn't mess up my data sheet
  sheet.clearContents(); 
//nA is a two dimensional array of rows that have column col unique. 
  sheet.getRange(1, 1, nA.length, nA[0].length).setValues(nA); 
}
```

As I said in the comments I used another sheet for the output because I didn't want to mess up my data sheet.  So you'll have to modify this a bit to get it to work for your application.

Comment: Thanks Cooper !

it works like a charm 
If could please explain the logic behind this - that would be great - would help me learn more. Like why did we use [col-1] instead of using [i][0]?

Thanks again !

Comment: Check out the comments.  Sorry I'm not very good at explaining things. In fact I normally have no idea what I'm going to do before I start.  I just kind of work through process incrementally.

Comment: Thank you Cooper - you have been a great help :-)